# elixir syntax word followed by colon and squiggly arrow and more

Tags: elixir

See Update Section for Updated question

Need some help understanding what this is in Elixir.

Is this an object/map like in JavaScript or Python or a function?

```
config :some_api,
  something: %{
    "user" => "xxx",
    "name" => "xxx"
  }

config :someStr, Some.Module.Repo, parameters: [somestring: "${USER}-some-str"]
```

UPDATE

I am looking through Elixir docs and cant really find a reference to these to syntaxes.

1)

```
def myFunc() do
[
 {Some.Module, someParam: 1},
 {SomeDef, [someParam: someData]}
]
```

I am guessing when this function gets called, it does everything in the list in order?

2)

```
def someFunc() do
 |>someFunc()
 ~> someModule.func()
```

What does the squiggly arrow do?

Comment: The question about the "squiggly arrow" (aka an [operator](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/operators.html)) should really be its own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elixir is one of those languages that can omit parentheses (like Ruby), so sometimes when you're reading code, you may not even realize that you're looking at a function with arguments.  `config` is one of those cases.  Specifically, you're looking at [`Config.config/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Config.html#config/2) and [`Config.config/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Config.html#config/3).

The first `config` statement:

```
config :some_api,
  something: %{
    "user" => "xxx",
    "name" => "xxx"
  }
```

actually could be rewritten as:

```
config(:some_api, something: %{"user" => "xxx", "name" => "xxx"})
```

The second argument is for options, which is a common convention in Elixir, similar to keyword-arguments in Python.  Like the functions with optional parentheses, keyword lists in Elixir have optional brackets, so the 2nd argument could be written as `[something: %{"user" => "xxx", "name" => "xxx"}]`, or to make it even longer form, you could write `[{:something, %{"user" => "xxx", "name" => "xxx"}}]`. -- the more verbose syntax can be a bit of a head-trip, so you can see why it's frequently abbreviated.

You can see a map (which is the Elixir equivalent of a Python dictionary or a Ruby hash): `%{"user" => "xxx", "name" => "xxx"}` -- the trick here is that when the keys are strings, they have to be quoted AND you have to use the fat-arrow `=>`.  If the keys were atoms, you could use an abbreviated syntax: `%{user: "xxx", name: "xxx"}`

The second config example uses `config/3`, so this:

```
config :someStr, Some.Module.Repo, parameters: [somestring: "${USER}-some-str"]
```

could be rewritten with parentheses as:

```
config(:someStr, Some.Module.Repo, [parameters: [somestring: "${USER}-some-str"]])
```

again, the last argument is frequently used for optional arguments (named `opts` by convention), and as before, it is a keyword list which frequently omits the optional brackets.

Hopefully that clears up the confusion; there are a few gotchas with the syntax, but not too many before things start making sense.

Answer (score 0):

Elixir has what are called [keyword lists](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Keyword.html), which are lists of 2-element tuples where the first element, the key, is an atom.

I tend to think of keyword lists as maps with 3 differences:

- keys have to be atoms
- duplicate keys are allowed
- order is preserved

Maps would also offer faster lookups when dealing with larger collections, but I don't know if I've ever seen a keyword list large enough to make maps more efficient.

Elixir also has a syntax where `[key: value]` represents `[{:key, :value}]` and also allows omitting the brackets in several situations.

So your first examples is the same as

```
config :some_api, [{:something, %{"user" => "xxx", "name" => "xxx"}}]
```

You most often see the bracket omision with options to functions. Like this:

```
IO.inspect(term, label: "some label")
```

Answer (score 0):

[elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) has great documentation. So when you are stumbled upon this to likewise thing, you might open an `iex` session and ask your doubts there.

```rb
❯ iex -S mix
Erlang/OTP 23 [erts-11.1.3] [...]
Interactive Elixir (1.11.2) [...]

iex|1 ▶ import Mix.Config
#⇒ Mix.Config

iex|2 ▶ h config

# a ton of information
```

*Note:* I blindly called `import Mix.Config` to fully replicate the env you have in your file.